# Basic line integral

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $C$ be curve along surfaces $z=\ln(1+x)$ and $y=x$ from $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,1,\ln(2))$. Calculate the work done by vector field

$$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(2x\sin(\pi y)-e^z)\mathbf{i}+(\pi x^2 \cos (\pi y)-3e^z)\mathbf{j}-xe^z \mathbf{k}$$

along the curve $C$.

I got this hint:
$$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=\overbrace{(2x\sin(\pi y)-e^z)\mathbf{i}+(\pi x^2 \cos \pi y)\mathbf{j}  -xe^z\mathbf{k}}^{=\mathbf{H}}-\overbrace{3e^z\mathbf{j}}^{=\mathbf{G}}$$
And that I should find the potential function $\phi$ and then $\nabla\phi=\mathbf{G}$. Also that $\int_C \nabla \mathbf{G} \cdot d\mathbf{s} =\phi(1,1,\ln(2))-\phi(0,0,0)$. But i'm still a bit confused at where to start..

EDIT. copied the question wrong. There is $e^z$ not $e^x$ in all terms.

Let's check if $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative:

$$\begin{align} \nabla\times\mathbf{F}&=\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} & \frac{\partial}{\partial{z}} \\ 2x\sin(\pi y)-e^z & \pi x^2 \cos (\pi y)-3e^z & -xe^z \end{vmatrix} \\
&=\mathbf{i}(0+3e^z)-\mathbf{j}(-e^z+e^z)+\mathbf{k}(2\pi x\cos(\pi y)-2\pi x\cos(\pi y)) \\&=3e^z\mathbf{i} \end{align}$$

It's not?? If I split $\mathbf{F}$ to $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{G}$, then $\mathbf{H}$ is conservative, but what to do with $\mathbf{G}$?

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if it has a potential function at all: a vector field $\boldsymbol F$ has a potential function if and only if $\nabla \times \boldsymbol F = 0$.

If it does have a potential, find it as follows:

(1) First integrate the $x$ component with respect to $x$,
$$ \phi = \int F_x(x,y,z) \, dx  = \phi_1 (x,y,z) + C_1(y,z),$$

since the constant of integration can be any function of $y$ and $z$.

(2) Then take the $y$-derivative of this,
$$ \frac{d \phi}{dy} = \frac{d\phi_1}{dy} + \frac{d C_1}{dy}.$$

Since this derivative must be the $y$-component of $\boldsymbol F$, we have the equation

$$ \frac{d C_1}{dy} = F_y - \frac{d\phi_1}{dy}.$$

Solving this gives $C_1$, up to an integration constant- any function of $z$.

(3) Repeat step (2) with $F_z$ and the $z$ derivative to find the $z$ dependence, leaving only an arbitrary constant left--this doesn't matter once you take the difference at two points.

(4) Check the potential function by computing the gradient $\nabla \phi$--it should be $\boldsymbol F$.

Comment: I got that, but after that, how do I find the work done by $\mathbf{F}$ along $C$? The trick with the potential?

Comment: Work is the difference in the potential between two points:

$$ W_{a \to b} = \phi(a) - \phi(b),$$

as long as $\boldsymbol F(x,y,z)$ is the force on the particle at that point.

Comment: Should I split $\mathbf{F}$ to two vector fields like in my original post? I don't think that $\mathbf{G}$ that my hint was has a potential...

Comment: Use the first point of my answer:

$$ \nabla \times \boldsymbol G \neq \boldsymbol 0,$$
so we know that $\boldsymbol  G$ does not have a potential function.

Comment: Okey I'll do some math and edit my question with an answer.

Comment: Can you check my edit on my OG post. It seems $\mathbf{F}$ is not conservative..

Comment: For $\boldsymbol G$ you are going to have to do the line integral normally:

$$\int \limits_{\mathcal C} \left( \boldsymbol G \cdot d \boldsymbol l \right).$$

It won't be that bad, because $3 e^{\ln(1 + x)}$ (after substituting the value for $z$) is an easy function to work with.

Comment: so for $\mathbf{G}$ I have to do parameterization? How does the surfaces come into play here.